# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process - maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, maximum-likelihood

I am studying Ornstein-Uhlenbeck model:
$$ dX_t = -A_0 X_t dt + dW_t,$$
where the initial value $X_0$ is given, and $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion.
G.Matulewicz in his doctoral thesis writes that the negative log-likelihood is given by
$$ L(A) = \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} (A X_t)^T dX_t  + \frac{1}{2T}\int_{0}^{T} (A X_t)^T A X_t dt $$

Then, the MLE estimator is given by 
$$ \hat{A} = - \left(\int_{0}^T dX_t X_t^T\right) \left(\int_{0}^T X_t X_t^T dt\right)^{-1}$$
However, I have no idea how the calculus between those lines follow and I would like to understand the technical part (to be able to use those techniques for other more general processes). Can anyone explain?